Building OFFLINE Desktop Application using C# in 2024
I am a back-end developer (windows services in C#), however our clients have recently started requesting that we add GUIs to our solutions and I am finding myself in a challenging situation with regards to GUI development in C#. NOTE: Our product runs on servers that DO NOT have internet access.
C# is moving towards RAZOR/BLAZOR/.NET MAUI desktop application development which, when you want to do anything that is "not basic" requires you to use .js libraries (for dropdowns, comboboxes, tables, charts, etc.) unless you want to manually code all of the associated HTML, and then the js resources as well.
It is possible to download and install some js libraries, however the majority are distributed through NPM or the CDN these days. I can install them via NPM and then manually copy and transport them with C# applications, but this is not always as straight forward as it seems (dependencies, compatibility, bloat).
Are there any GUI frameworks that work with C# and .NET Core 6+ that can be easily leveraged without internet connectivity? Or should we use an alternate technology for our GUI development?
Our entire department are back-end developers who now need to figure out the best ways for doing front-end work... any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

What about WPF?

@kyrlon - thank you for the suggestion.  I was (mistakenly) under the impression that WPF was being replace by BLAZER and WinGUI.  I'll take a look.

What do you mean by "replaced"? You can download older Visuals and frameworks like that at any time.

@Destroy666 I am assuming he means he assumed that WPF was being "deprecated" (or worst obsolete at this point in time) in favor of the ones he mentioned.

@kyrlon you are correct.

Too little information.
